# swipe.js Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'next'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep having this error when i try to implement swipe.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'next'
```

I am loading content via ajax

jquery:

```
    var container = $("#wrapper");

    url = this.href + " .span9";

    container.load(url, function(){
       var $galNav = $("<a href='#' onclick='slider.prev();return false;'>prev</a> <a href='#' onclick='slider.next();return false;'>next</a>");
       container.append($galNav);
       window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
    });
```

The html I am loading:

```
<div id='slider'>
  <ul>
    <li style='display:block'>1</li>
    <li style='display:none'>2</li>
    <li style='display:none'>3</li>
    <li style='display:none'>4</li>
    <li style='display:none'>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I followed [swipe.js](http://swipejs.com/) but I don't get why I am having that error and doesn't work

Comment: `slider.next()` calls the method `next` on the element with ID `slider`. DOM elements don't have a method `next`.

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure what I should be doing now, I followed what they said, am i missing something?

Comment: Use `window.mySwipe.next()` instead. See the "API & Requirements" tab. It looked like you copied their HTML. On the page they actually use `var slider =  new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), ...);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slider` is a DOM element, with no `next` function.  You may need to refer to the swipe object:

```
mySwipe.next();
```